# i cant make rollup in sql server to work as i want

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I am using an SQL query to produce the following results.
I have around ten products in a table in a database , and i also have sales in another table.

My products have some special attributes.

1. there is a flag that is used to group the products to SMALLV and BIGV. The flag is just true or false
2. another numeric variable that determines the alcohol in each product. It is decimal and has a value of 0.40 or 0.42
3. another numeric variable that holds the volume of the product . It takes different values from 0.05 or 0.10 or 0.20 or 1 or 5 . These are Liters.

I built a query to get sales of all those products but they must be categorized. I use a lot of Sum and so far it works great.
The problem start when I ask for sub totals. It confuses me and I can't get the right results.

m
My query so far is something like,

```
Select it.itemdescription as item
,it.vatpercent as vat
,sum(it.AQty) as firstquant
,sum(it.bQty) as secquant
,itm.userdefnum02 as volume
,itm.userdefnum01 as [alc%]
,(itm.userdefnum02*itm.USERDEFNUM01*(sum(it.aQty))) as alclit
,(12.25*itm.userdefnum02*itm.USERDEFNUM01*(sum(it.aQty))) as tax
,itm.HEUSERDEFBOOL01 as flag
From centlines it
inner join items itm on itm.code=it.itemcode
inner join commercialentries ce on ce.dentid=it.dentid
group by itm.userdefnum01,it.vatpercent,itm.userdefbool01 ,it.itemdescription,itm.userdefnum02,ITM.code
```

Now I want subtotals of the products that have the flag enabled and have the same 'alc%' and same 'vat'.

Is this possible?

My query is big so I just changed it to show you what I try to acomplish.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I don't see any "subtotal" in your query, and I also don't see any ROLLUP() which is an actual function. Subtotals are usually calculated in a different layer (reporting/presentation).
What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could possibly use grouping sets. For example `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (itm.userdefnum01, it.vatpercent, itm.userdefbool01, it.itemdescription, itm.userdefnum02, ITM.code), (itm.userdefbool01), () )` but your intended result is not clear.

Comment: Not clear on what you want, but recommend you look into using WITH ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS, etc. https://www.sqlshack.com/group-by-rollup-for-data-analysis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `GROUPING SETS`

```sql
select
  it.itemdescription as item
 ,it.vatpercent as vat
 ,sum(it.AQty) as firstquant
 ,sum(it.bQty) as secquant
 ,itm.userdefnum02 as volume
 ,itm.userdefnum01 as [alc%]
 ,itm.userdefnum02 * itm.USERDEFNUM01 * sum(it.aQty) as alclit
 ,itm.userdefnum02 * itm.USERDEFNUM01 * sum(it.aQty) * 12.25 as tax
 ,itm.HEUSERDEFBOOL01 as flag
from centlines it
inner join items itm on itm.code = it.itemcode
inner join commercialentries ce on ce.dentid = it.dentid
group by grouping sets (
  (itm.HEUSERDEFBOOL01, it.vatpercent, it.itemdescription, itm.userdefnum01, itm.userdefnum02),
  (itm.HEUSERDEFBOOL01, it.vatpercent, itm.userdefnum01)
);
```